# Bind the dropdownlist selected value and its textbox value to Model MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form to create a New login information. During the post, i have to bind the login information along with the security questions and answers. I have bound the security questions to a dropdownlist from the DB. how to bind the question ID and text value (for answer) to the model and pass it to the DB table?

here is my code

**Model**

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Question1")]
public List<string> Question1 { get; set; }
[Required]       
[Display(Name = "Question2")]
public string Question2 { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Answer1")]
public List<string> Answer1 { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Answer2")]
public string Answer2 { get; set; }
public SelectList QuestionList { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewLogin()
{
    myDB dbCon = new myDB();         
    ViewBag.QuestionList = new SelectList(dbCon.GetQuestion(), "ID", "Value");
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewLogin()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         p.Email = model.Email;
         p.pass = model.password;
         // how to get the Question ID and Answer here ?
         //each user has its own ID where this ID is related to two questions ID in the database
     }
     return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ID,new SelectList(Model.QuestionList,"ID","Value"),"Select a question")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer1, new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ID,new SelectList(Model.QuestionList,"ID","Value"),"Select a question")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer2, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

[image]

Comment: Property `Answer1` needs to be typeof `string`, not `List<string>` and properties `Question1` and `Question2` need to be type of `int` and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Question1, new SelectList(...))`

Comment: thanks, will check out and get back. I have three tables,one for login info, one for security questions and one for storing the answers for the security questions. So one user will have two answers with two question ID's, how do i Bind it to the model? that is my question here

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly, but I assume your 'Answers' table has fields for UserID, QuestionID and the answer?

Comment: yes, you're correct. have these three fields. thanks a lot for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you model to (attributes omitted)

```
public class LoginModel
{
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public int Question1 { get; set; } // change
  public int Question2 { get; set; } // change
  public string Answer1 { get; set; } // change
  public string Answer2 { get; set; }
  public SelectList QuestionList { get; set; }
}
```

And in the controller

```
myDB dbCon = new myDB();   

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewLogin()
{
  // Initialize the model and assign the SelectList
  LoginModel model = new LoginModel()
  {
    QuestionList = SelectList(dbCon.GetQuestion(), "ID", "Value")
  };
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewLogin(LoginModel model)
{
  // Save the user and get their ID
  // Save the values of UserID, Question1, Answer1 
  // and UserID, Question2, Answer2 to your Answers table
}
```

And in the view

```
@model LoginModel
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Question1, Model.QuestionList, "Select a question")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer1)
// ditto for Question2 and Answer2
```

Side note: You will probably want to have a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[NotEqualTo]` or similar validation attribute on `Question2` so the user cannot select the same question again

Answer (score 0):

Here changing model means you need to create one Viewmodel as per your view and map your property of models to this viewModel respectively
.